# Make Grails Geb tests transactional

Tags: testing, grails, spock, geb

I need my Geb tests to be transactional (to rollback at the end of each test), how can I achieve that?

I tried 'static transactional = true' and the @Transactional annotation in both class and methods and it doesn't work.

P.D.: My tests extends from GebReportingSpec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is technically impossible:

https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEB-238